# How to switch typescript version on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, linux, typescript, ubuntu

How to switch typescript version on Ubuntu?

I have installed two versions of Typescript on my Ubuntu, how can I switch to another one?

```
> tsc -v
Version 3.9.3
```

Comment: Typically you'd do this at a *project* level, use the local tsc via an entry in the package file's "scripts" object.

Comment: one possibility to directly call the proper `tsc` is to write the full path to it (wherever you have it installed), and better, create a simlink to it "tsc2" in `/usr/bin` for instance.